# why FileNotFoundError does not work in python file

Tags: python, json, try-except

I have username.json empty file. I need to ask user a name and greet him and save its name in json file otherwise it already exists inside of json file, I need to use name and write 'welcome back '  + username

```
import json

filename = 'username.json'
try:
    with open(filename) as file_obj:
        username = json.loads(file_obj)
except FileNotFoundError:
    username = input('What is your name ? ')
    with open(filename, 'w') as file_obj:
        json.dump(username, file_obj)
        print('We will remember you as ' + username + ' !')
else:
    print('Welcome back ' + username + '!')
```

But I have faced errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    username = json.load(file_obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Can you post the content of the JSON file? It seems there is a parsing issue with it.

Comment: there is just one string 'Oksana'

Comment: A json file should have a json structure, eg: `{"name": "Oksana"}`

Comment: Or you could forget json and just store each name on a line in the file.

Comment: The error occurs because `FileNotFoundError` only catches a "file does not exist", and you clearly get another error – which is reported as usual because you do *not* catch it.

Answer (score 1):

you may use:

```
import os
import json

filename = 'username.json'
username = input('What is your name ? ')

if os.path.isfile(filename ): # check if the file exist:
    if os.stat(filename ).st_size == 0: # check if the file is empty
        with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
            json.dump([username], fp)
            print('We will remember you as ' + username + ' !')

    else:
        with open(filename) as fp:
            user_names = json.load(fp)

        with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
            if username in user_names : 
                print('Welcome back ' + username + '!')
            else:
                user_names.append(username)
                json.dump(user_names, fp)
                print('We will remember you as ' + username + ' !')

else:
    with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump([username])
        print('We will remember you as ' + username + ' !')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import json

filename = 'username.json'
try:
    with open(filename) as file_obj:
        username = json.loads(file_obj)["name"]
except FileNotFoundError:
    username = input('What is your name ? ')
    with open(filename, 'w') as file_obj:
        json_data = {"name": username}
        json.dump(json_data, file_obj)
        print('We will remember you as ' + username + ' !')
else:
    print('Welcome back ' + username + '!')
```

Comment: Surely this suffers from the same problem as the OP when the file is empty.

Comment: This example relies on a file not being present. An empty file was generated with the code in the original question. @Оксана Шух try deleting the empty file first.